# (Box and Whisker Plot Problem) Why is the answer choice 3 instead of choice 2?

Tags: statistics

(Look at the link below)
Problem #$6$ has me confused. The answer key of the textbook I am using states that the answer is choice $3$. But shouldn't the answer be choice $2$ ( $7$ students ) because the numbers, $81$ through $88$, are below Q$3$?

[image]

Comment: I believe you are correct: the given range is between the median and the 3rd quartile, which contains $1/4$ of the students.

Comment: The question in the book is not well put (see my answer below). A possible meaningful question would be "AT LEAST how many students scored from 81 to 88?" Then, you can derive the answer 7 by applying the properties of the quartiles as follows:
AT LEAST 14 scores ($50\%$ of the scores) must be greater than or equal to the second quartile (the median). AT MOST 7 scores ($25\%$ of the scores) can be greater than the third quartile (assumed to be 88). So, AT LEAST 7 students scored from 81 to 88.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct. The plot shows that the median ($2$nd quartile) is $81$, and that the $3$rd quartile is at $88$, so this range should contain exactly $28(0.25)=7$ students.

Answer (score 1):

The question cannot be answered from the given box plot.

Example:

Any **ordered** score set for $28$ students of the following type would produce the same box plot:

(I have difficulty to read the  $Q_3$ from your picture, so I assume it to be $Q_3= 88$.)
$$\begin{pmatrix}
Place: & 1 & \cdots & 7 & 8 & \cdots & 14 & 15 & \cdots & 21 & 22 & \cdots & 28 \\
Score: & 62 & \cdots & 71 & 71 & \cdots & 81 & 81 & \cdots & 88 & 88 & \cdots & 92 
\end{pmatrix}$$

This would give possible numbers of scores from 81 to 88 ranging from 9 to 19.

If we assume that $Q_3 = \frac{x_{21}+x_{22}}{2}$, then consider the follwoing score set:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
Place: & 1 & \cdots & 7 & 8 & \cdots & 14 & 15 & \cdots & 21 & 22 & \cdots & 28 \\
Score: & 62 & \cdots & 71 & 71 & \cdots & 80 & 82 & \cdots & 87 & 89 & \cdots & 92 
\end{pmatrix}$$
This would give the answer of 7 scores ranging from 81 to 88.